# hidden variable in html

Tags: html, variables, hidden

I am working in Ruby Sinatra.  In Ruby, I create a nokogiri object (@xml) that the erb page has access to.  In the post, I need to have access to that same object, so I create a hidden variable like so:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="xml" value= '<%= @xml %>' >
```

However, in some cases, the page displays a bunch of text from the @xml object that I don't want displayed.  As a workaround, I moved it offscreen, like this:

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:5000px; top:200px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="xml" value= '<%= @xml %>' >
</div>
```

but there must be a better way.  Suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Would this be better suited to be saved to the database, then looked up by an ID in the post?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be in content of the @xml object. You should encode the special characters before printing the variable into value attribute.

If the @xml object contains a single quote, browser will interpret it like the end of value attribute.

Take a look at [HTMLentities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) library for Ruby.